# redirect to a page using bootstrap angular js button as opposed to url.action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How do I convert the following url.action link to a boot strapped button.

```
<a data-ng-href="@Url.Action("Create", "Profile")" target="_self">Create New  </a>**strong text**
```

This button upon click needs to redirect the current page to Create Action and Profile Controller.

I am trying to bootstrap and angularize a legacy asp.net mvc 4 app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an anchor tag a class of button which makes it look like a button but it can still contain a href. The alternative is in the controller to have a function to change the path using angulars $location service, eg:

```
$scope.setLocation = function(url) {
  $location.path(url)
};
```

in the html:

```
<div class="button" ng-click="setLocation('path/to/location');
```